# UPnP MediaServer for stream2android

Tags: android, upnp

I am working on an UPnP implementation for Android. I have downloaded a MediaRenderer code [`stream2android`](http://code.google.com/p/stream2android/). I compiled it and it's working fine. Now I want to install a MediaServer.
I have few questions.

1. Which MediaServer should I install for `stream2android`?
2. Has the server to be on an Android device or can I install it on other Linux too?
3. Can I install and linux based MediaServer.

Any input will be helpful.

Edit:-
One more thing i want to ask, android framework has already some class like

```
WifiP2pUpnpServiceInfo http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/nsd/WifiP2pUpnpServiceInfo.html

WifiP2pUpnpServiceRequest http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/nsd/WifiP2pUpnpServiceRequest.html
```

so instead of using any library, can we directly use this class. By reading these class it's not very clear, how we can use them. I am not asking for any sample code or something, just a little detail about these classes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `stream2android` is MediaRenderer only, you cannot "install MediaServer for it". It is using [CyberLink](http://www.cybergarage.org/twiki/bin/view/Main/CyberLinkForJava) Java library for basic UPnP support and builds just MediaRenderer on it. If you want `stream2android` to act as MediaServer too, you can implement it yourself on the CyberLink. Get an idea at [x360mediaserver](http://x360mediaserver.googlecode.com/svn-history/r26/trunk/cybergarage/org/cybergarage/upnp/media/server/MediaServer.java) which implements MediaServer with CyberLink.

   Or you can install [any of the existing MediaServers for Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UPnP_AV_media_servers_and_clients#Android).
2. MediaServer can be any device capable of TCP and UDP socket communication. It is roughly equivalent to a webserver. So it can be your Android device, other Linux too. Or Windows. Or Symbian if you want.
3. I don't understand the question.

Comment: thanks for the reply, your reply is so useful for me. My third question is this, that i got a link [http://sourceforge.net/projects/upnpmediaserver/], which is a media-server on linux. will this server work with stream2android application. Basically i wanted to know any media-server will work with any media-render?

Comment: @ManishaKhare Yes, you can expect any UPnP media server to work with any UPnP media renderer

Comment: @simonc okey, you have resolved my confusion. thanks for the reply.

Comment: @ManishaKhare upnpmediaserver seems to be a native app: written in C and depending on Linux-specific C libraries. Which means that it won't work on Android. But why do you insist on having Linux application on Android, when there is dozen of already existing MediaServers for Android? I gave you the link in answer 1). I can personally confirm that BubbleUPnP works as expected.

Comment: @PavelZdenek, okey, then i'll use android MediaServer. actually i installed one mediaserver apk on my simulator, but i am not able to run mediaserver and renderer at the same time, so i thought i install the server on linux machine and run renderer on androidemulator.